# Gherkin Testcafe invalid installation --> version dependencies

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, gherkin

i am currently trying a new project for testing and using gherkin-testcafe package for the tests. But i am getting the following error message when i use this command. I never installed cucumber globally and i also tried the solutions given here [gherkin-testcafe invalid installation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/installation.md#invalid-installations).
`gherkin-testcafe chrome ./tests/**/*.ts ./tests/**/*.feature`:

[image: error message when running gherkin-testcafe]

I defined simple tests (example ones from testcafe) and createt the gherkin .feature file for it.

The packages i am using (I also tried it whithout the *@cucumber/cucumber* package and with higher version numbers. *gherkin-testcafe@6.0.0* and *testcafe@2.3.1* ):
[image: local and global packages.]

Here is the project structure, the test and .feature file.
[image: project structure]

**firstTests.ts**

```
import { Given, When, Then } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

Given('I load the testpage', async (t) => {
  // The first argument of Given, When and Then will be a regex that matches the step.
  // The second argument is a function that takes TestCafé's test controller object as a parameter.
  await t.navigateTo('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');
});

When('I type in a text', async (t, params) => {
  // Captured parameters in the step regex will be passed as the second argument to the test implementation.
  // "When Something great happens" will call this function with `["great"]` as `params`.
  await t
    .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
});

When('I click on submit', async (t, [param1, param2]) => {
  // You can use regular array destructuring to access params directly.
  // "When Something great and awesome happens" will result in `"great"` as `param1` and `"awesome"` as `param2`.
  await t
    .click('#submit-button')
});

Then('It should thank me', async (t) => {
  // Test code is the same as TestCafé's test function accepts.
  await t
    .expect(Selector('#article-header').innerText).eql('Thank you, John Smith!');
});

Then(
  'use Cucumber Expressions to get {int}, {float}, {word}, {string}, etc',
  async (t, [intParam, floatParam, singleWordParam, stringParam]) => {
    // You can use "Cucumber Expressions" instead of regex to get the parameters in the desired types.
    // It's also possible to add custom parameter types if needed.
    await t.expect(typeof intParam).eql('number');
  }
);
```

**firstTests.feature**

```
Feature: FirstTest Feature Name# Enter feature name here
  # Enter feature description here

  Scenario: FirstTest scenario name# Enter scenario name here
    # Enter steps here
    Given I load the testpage
    When I type in a text
    When I click on submit
    Then It should thank me
```

**Edit 1:**
Problem appiers on MacOs and Ubuntu.

Comment: The question is not directly related to TestCafe, so it's better to ask the author of the `gherkin-testcafe` module or in the `cucumber-js` repository.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

For some reasons (maybe i was it, don't know right now), in the global node_modules the cucumber package was installed. I deleted it and afterwards it worked.